# __webpack_require__ error in angular project when running karma/jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I have this error, following a few minor update.

I just have update a few angular stuff, but I don't know what I have to fix in my karma.config to fix it.

The fun part is, I don't have any config of webpack anywhere.

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'XXXXXService')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'XXXXXXService')
    at Module.XXXXXService (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/main.js:12230:113)
    at Module.15940 (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/@shared/services/YYYYYYYYY.service.ts:30:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.22076 (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/main.js:12251:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.19420 (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/main.js:8888:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.9509 (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/main.js:10190:110)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Module.27601 (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/main.js:7256:72)
```

My karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
```

// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage/new'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/localize": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "13.3.11",
    "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "8.3.0",
    "angular-google-tag-manager": "1.5.1",
    "angular-spec-creator": "^1.7.0",
    "angular-unit-test-generator": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.34",
    "ngx-google-analytics": "11.2.1",
    "rxjs": "7.5.5",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "13.0.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "13.3.11",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "3.0.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "7.0.3",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "1.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.10.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.12",
    "@types/node": "12.20.55",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "hads": "2.1.0",
    "htmlhint": "0.16.3",
    "https-proxy-agent": "5.0.1",
    "husky": "4.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "3.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "ngx-spec": "^2.1.5",
    "openapi-typescript-codegen": "^0.23.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.1",
    "pretty-quick": "3.0.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "stylelint": "13.7.2",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "4.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "20.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.18.0",
    "ts-node": "10.7.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0"
  },
```